# Installing LAMP on SSD

Tags: ssd, lamp

I've already installed LAMP but because I'll be doing local dev work on drupal sites I got an SSD and installed that (+ partitioned and formatted it). So I can access my SSD now. But I'm thinking I'd like to install LAMP on the SSD so I can do dev work for drupal sites there.

Does anyone know if that's possible (it won't have an OS on it). Do I need to add an OS to it as well? and if not, what's the commands for installing programs on another drive?

Thanks so much! I'm really new on Linux. Trying to get myself un-Windows'ed after 20 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem, once you installed Lampp you can start the services by going into the terminal and typing:

```
sudo /your/own/directory/lampp/lampp start
```